# Click button navigate Bootstrap tab using Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have done button click navigate to next bootstrap tab using jquery with below code snippet

```
$("#btn").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#mytabs a[href="#menu1"]').tab('show');
}
```

How to achieve the same functionality with Angular

```
buttonClick(event){
  //how to show particular tab ?? 
   $('#mytabs a[href="#menu1"]').tab('show');
}
```

I have tried like this. but getting error as `e[b] is not a function`

I don't want to use ngBootstrap. Is there any way to achieve this with Twitter Bootstrap alone.

Comment: You could use ngbootstrap : https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabset/examples

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Is there any way to do with twitter bootstrap alone..